# javascript: form select option and input field

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I have an form `input` field, when a user types "text 2", I want that "text 2" selected in the form `select`:

```html
<select id="formsel">
    <option value="text 1">text 1</option>
    <option value="text 3">text 2</option>
    <option value="text 3">text 3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='input' />
```

I get the value from the `input` like this:

```
var input_val = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

But I can not select the option from the dynamic form `select` with

```
document.form.formsel.value = input_val;
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery has warped me - all I can think of is `$("#formsel option:selected").text()`

Comment: cool - posted as answer in that case.

Comment: @JasperM [Does my answer help?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13180789/701092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you're using jQuery (you should tag all questions with jQuery if that's the case).

This should get you what you want

```
var selectedText = $("#formsel option:selected").text()
```

Comment: Unless he meant something else, what he's asking for is the opposite, wanting to select the value based on the typed text, not get the value from the select list. Though his response to your comment suggests this is the correct answer. Oi.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't show the `form` you are trying to access with `document.form`, so I'm assuming there is no form. Try accessing the `select` by its id. This seems to work for me:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function()
{
    var input_val = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('formsel').value = input_val;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo.

```
<option value="text 3">text 2</option>
```

Should be:

```
<option value="text 2">text 2</option>
```

Comment: Even so, that won't fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('formsel'),
    txt = document.getElementById('input').value, node;

for ( var i = nodes.length; i--; ) {

    node = nodes[i];

    if ( txt === nodes[i].value ) {

        node.selected = true; break;

    }

}
```